# Color Cahnge In Buy Or Sell

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
export default function OrdersTab(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.AuthReducer);
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.AuthReducer);
  const { webData } = useSelector((state) => state.websiteDBReducer);

  const { user_order_pending, user_order_close } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.coinDBReducer
  );
  const [pendingOrder, setpendingOrder] = useState([]);
  const [closeOrder, setcloseOrder] = useState([]);
  const coin = props.match.params.id.split("-");

  // State for the filter
  const [isFilterActive, setIsFilterActive] = useState(false);

  const handleFilter = (e) => {
    // Toggle the filter state
    setIsFilterActive(!isFilterActive);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Memoize the filtered pending orders
    const filteredPendingOrders = user_order_pending.filter((order) =>
      isFilterActive ? order.currency_type === coin[0] : true
    );

    // Memoize the filtered close orders
    const filteredCloseOrders = user_order_close.filter((order) =>
      isFilterActive ? order.currency_type === coin[0] : true
    );

    // Only update the state if the filtered orders have changed
    if (
      JSON.stringify(filteredPendingOrders) !== JSON.stringify(pendingOrder) ||
      JSON.stringify(filteredCloseOrders) !== JSON.stringify(closeOrder)
    ) {
      setpendingOrder(filteredPendingOrders);
      setcloseOrder(filteredCloseOrders);
    }
  }, [user_order_pending, user_order_close, isFilterActive, coin]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = user?.params ? user.params.token : user.token;
    if (activeTab == 0 && token) {
      N_pendingOrder(token)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.status === 200) {
            dispatch({
              type: SET_USER_ORDER_PENDING,
              data: res.params.trade_history.pending,
              pending_order_loading: false,
            });
          } else {
            console.log("error to fetch open and close orders: ", res);
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    }
    if (activeTab == 1 && token) {
      N_completeOrder(token)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.status === 200) {
            dispatch({
              type: SET_USER_ORDER_CLOSE,
              data: res.params.trade_history.compleated,
              close_order_loading: false,
            });
          } else {
            console.log("error to fetch open and close orders: ", res);
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    }
  }, [activeTab]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setpendingOrder(
      user_order_pending.sort(
        (a, b) => Number(b.timestamp) - Number(a.timestamp)
      )
    );
    setcloseOrder(
      user_order_close.sort((a, b) => Number(b.timestamp) - Number(a.timestamp))
    );
  }, [user_order_pending, user_order_close]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="card mt-2 mb-2">
        <div className="card-header p-0">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <div className="nav nav-pills" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                <div
                  className={`nav-item nav-link ${
                    activeTab === 0 ? "active" : ""
                  }`}
                  id="nav-home-tab"
                  data-toggle="tab"
                  role="tab"
                  aria-controls="nav-home"
                  aria-selected="true"
                  onClick={() => setActiveTab(0)}
                >
                  Open Orders
                </div>
                <div
                  className={`nav-item nav-link ${
                    activeTab === 1 ? "active" : ""
                  }`}
                  id="nav-profile-tab"
                  data-toggle="tab"
                  onClick={() => setActiveTab(1)}
                  role="tab"
                  aria-controls="nav-profile"
                  aria-selected="false"
                >
                  Completed Orders
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-8 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
              <div
                className="flex"
                onClick={handleFilter}
                style={{ marginRight: "10px", cursor:"pointer" }}
              >
                <FaFilter /> {isFilterActive?'Show':"Hide"} Other Pair
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="order_height custom_scrollbar">
          {!isLoggedIn ? (
            <div className="tab-content orders">
              <LoginORSignup />
            </div>
          ) : null}
          {activeTab === 0 && isLoggedIn ? <div className=""></div> : null}
          {isLoggedIn ? (
            <>
              <div className="tab-content orders">
                <div
                  className={`tab-pane fade ${
                    activeTab === 0 ? "show active" : ""
                  }`}
                  id="open-order"
                >
                  <table className="exchange_tbl order-book-table table_striped">
                    <thead className="sticky_thead">
                      <tr>
                        <th>
                          <h6>Pair</h6>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          <h6>Amount</h6>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          <h6>Price</h6>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          <h6>Total</h6>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          <h6>Executed</h6>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          <h6>Completed On</h6>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          <h6>Delete</h6>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                      {pendingOrder && pendingOrder?.length > 0
                        ? pendingOrder.map((d, index) => {
                            return (
                              <OrderRow
                                {...d}
                                key={index}
                                // deleteOrder={(order_id, order_type) =>
                                //   deleteOrder(order_id, order_type)
                                // }
                                user_id={
                                  user?.params ? user.params.token : user.token
                                }
                              />
                            );
                          })
                        : null}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>

                  {pendingOrder?.length === 0 ? (
                    <div className="text-center py-5 text-muted" colspan="3">
                      <div>
                        <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o fs-2 text-muted"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div className="fs-12">No Open Orders !</div>
                    </div>
                  ) : null}
                  {loading ? <Loader /> : null}
                </div>
```

When I but the coin open order show green color other and then i sell coin then show red color in the screen  and user can  see green or red color  in open order section changes open order can change the color in green or red in the scree  i acn try many times nothing to do chamges only open order section